# It is possible to click a select-box with Powershell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, powershell, drop-down-menu, onclick

I have a question about Powershell and the automation function with IE.

I created a script thats starts IE and navigates to a website. On this website you can find a form (textbox, submit button, select box). Now I can fill the textbox and I can press the submit button, but how can I select an entry from the select box? If I click manually on an entry the onlick event starts.

```html
<select id="*********" class="form-required" name="******" style="" tabindex="201" onChange="change*****Type(0);">
```

I can't use the values of the selectbox. If I use them, the onclick event doesn't work and I get an error on the website so I can't continue.

Here is my Code:

This is for the Login and it works!

```
$ieDoc = $ieApp.document

$inputs = $ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
($inputs | where {$_.name -eq "user"}).value = $username
($inputs | where {$_.name -eq "password"}).value = $Global:password

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
$submit = $ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")
($submit | where {$_.name -eq "login"}).click()
```

this one for the next site with the html form

```
$ieApp.navigate($Global:URLStep1)
start-sleep -Seconds 4
$selects = $ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("select")
($selects | where {$_.name -eq "selbox"}).value  = $Global:value
```

i can set the select box by value, but this method dont start the onclick event from the select box. I need a method where start the onclick event.

Anybody know a solution?

Sry i edited my Post and put my Code in this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Show your code. We aren't psychics.

Comment: Your question doesn't go into much detail or contain any of the code you are using. Check out [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for help with asking a great question that will get you a good answer.

Comment: I edited my Post. thx for your help